# How can I get what key was pressed in Unity?

Tags: unity, input, text

## Description

I'm working on a chat that will immediately record input when any (compatible) key is pressed, so I need to record the keys pressed and turn them into a string.

## Attempted Solutions

#### 1) Listen to every key-press with a script and push it inside a Text component

I like this one most, because the chat is simple enough that I'm better off with a custom Input Field component, and I get all the control I need.

However, I don't know how to get what key was pressed in a frame, short of checking for every single one (and the shift modifier, too). This is inefficient both for me, the developer, and the computer.

#### 2) Automatically focus an Input Field when any key is pressed

Unity has a handy `Input.anyKey` boolean field that's `true` whenever any key is pressed, but I need to save that first key press and insert it manually into the Input Field or else it will be lost, as the Input Field only listens for key-presses once it's in focus.

That means I need a way to record key presses, and then we're back to solution #1.

Comment: Have you considered focusing the input field before the player starts typing, rather than just-in-time? This is how most input fields that accept text work. If you use an InputField component, it exposes an event that will tell you what text was entered into it, giving you a chance to validate or modify it as you need.

Comment: How do I focus it, though? The field *needs* to be focused on (compatible) key presses, and no other way — it's a design requirement. Doesn't that repeat the mistake of solution #2?

Comment: 1. [EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.html) 2. What is taking focus away from the input field? If you can return focus to it after anything takes it away, using eg. the EndEdit event, then it will already have focus before the player presses the next key.